# PDF from ERB template with PDFKit and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

In my Rails application I'd like to have a special route to download a custom PDF.

This PDF should be generated via PDFKit from an ERB template in my application. Instead of describing what I'd like to achieve, I better paste some non-executable but commented code:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def download_my_list_as_pdf
    # The template uses the instance variables below
    @user_id = params[:user_id]
    @items = ['first_item', 'second_item']

    # This line describes what I'd like to do but behaves not like I want ;)
    # Render the ERB template and save the rendered html in a variable
    # I'd also use another layout
    rendered_html = render :download_my_list_as_pdf

    kit = PDFKit.new(rendered_html, page_size: 'A4')
    kit.to_pdf

    pdf_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/my_list.pdf"
    kit.to_file(pdf_file_path)

    send_file pdf_file_path, type: 'application/pdf'

    # This is the message I'd like to show at the end
    # But using 'render' more than once is not allowed
    render plain: 'Download complete'
  end
end
```

I wasn't able to find an answer to this problem yet, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`render_to_string(*args, &block)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string)
>
> Raw rendering of a template to a string.
>
> It is similar to render, except that it does not set the response_body
>   and it should be guaranteed to always return a string.

`render` does not return a string it sets the `response_body` of the response.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def download_my_list_as_pdf
    # The template uses the instance variables below
    @user_id = params[:user_id]
    @items = ['first_item', 'second_item']

    # This line describes what I'd like to do but behaves not like I want ;)
    # Render the ERB template and save the rendered html in a variable
    # I'd also use another layout
    rendered_html = render_string(:download_my_list_as_pdf)

    kit = PDFKit.new(rendered_html, page_size: 'A4')
    kit.to_pdf

    pdf_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/my_list.pdf"
    kit.to_file(pdf_file_path)

    send_file pdf_file_path, type: 'application/pdf'
  end
end
```

However if you are sending a file you cannot send text or html as well. This is not a limitation of Rails but rather how HTTP works. One request - one response.

Usually javascript is used to create notifications surrounding file downloads. But consider first if its really needed as its pretty annoying to users as the browser usually tells you that you downloaded a file anyways.

Comment: Hey @max, thanks for your answer and the additional explanation! Shows again that it's easy to find something when you [know what you are looking for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) ;)

Went with this now: `rendered_html = render_to_string :download_my_list_as_pdf, layout: false`